# Navigating from nested navigation wrapping component and rendering header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

## Epic

In my application I have **Tab Navigator**  in which one of the screens is called **Employees**. On the EmployeesScreen I have a list of employees and a button "Invite" which **redirects me to InviteEmployeeWizardForm**(inviteEmployee key). InviteEmployeeWizardForm is declared "on the same level" as TabNavigation(both are part of **RootStackNavigator**) because I want it to overlap my TabNavigation.

InviteEmployeeWizardForm is designed to be a stack navigator in which each screen represents some step in a wizard form. Moreover, InviteEmployeeWizardForm  is a **NavigatorWrappingScreen**(according to [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting#Nesting-a-Navigator-in-a-Component)) because on each form step I have some common components like a button which I want to stay in place while the form body represented by different screens will transistion.

## Figure

[image]

## Code

Employee screen inside Tab navigator

```
const TabNavigation = TabNavigator({
    // …
    employees: EmployeesScreen /** 1 */
    // …
})


/** 1 */
class EmployeesScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Button onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('inviteEmployee')}>Invite</Button>
  }
}
```

Form navigator
    /** 5 */

```
const routeConfigs={ 
    step0:{
        screen: DataScreen,   /** 2 */
        //params: {
        //  title: 'Information'   /** 5b */
        //}
    },
    step1:{
        screen: PrivilegesScreen   /** 3*/
    }
};

const navigationConfigs = { 
    navigationOptions: { header:null }, /** 5a */
    initialRouteName:  'step0',
};

const WizardFormNavigation = StackNavigator(routeConfigs,navigationConfigs);  /** 5 */
```

Form steps components and repeated declaration of header(works only this way):

```
class DataScreen  extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    /** 6 */
    header: props => 
        <NavHeader navigation={props.navigation} title={'Information'} labels={['Information','Privileges']} activeIndex={0}/>
    }
    // ..
}
class PrivilegesScreen  extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        /** 6 */
        header: props => 
            <NavHeader navigation={props.navigation} title={'Privileges'} labels={['Information','Privileges']} activeIndex={1}/>
    }
    // ..
}
```

Screen that wraps form navigator

```
/** 4*/
class InviteEmployeeWizardForm extends Component  {
static navigationOptions={header:null};

    // …

    render(){

    return(
        <Viewstyle={{flex:1}}>
            { /** 5 */ }
            <WizardFormNavigation navigation = {this.props.navigation} />

            <Button onPress={this.nextStep} }>Invite</ButtonPrimary>
        </View>
        )
    }
}

InviteEmployeeWizardForm.router = WizardFormNavigation .router;
```

Questions:

1. How do I navigate from InviteEmployeeWizardForm (step1) to EmployeesScreen?

   What I have tried? (inside InviteEmployeeWizardForm nextStep method)

   - 1.a

     ```
     const redirectAction = NavigationActions.reset({
           index: 0,
           actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({
             routeName: 'employees'
           }) ]
         });

     this.props.navigation.dispatch(redirectAction);
     ```

     I get: There is no route defined for key employees. Must be one of: step0, step1.
   - 1.b.

     ```
     this.props.navigation.navigate('employees');
     ```

     Surprisingly, this works (not sure why?) but I want to reset navigation(pop InviteEmployeeWizardForm steps), not put this screen on top of the stack.
   - 1.c.

     ```
     this.props.navigation.goBack('step0');
     ```

     No effect
2. Why when I try to extract my custom header  (/** 6 */)  to  /** 5a */  and supply title prop with param title(navigation.state.params.title instead of fixed value) defined in  /**5b*/  it doesn't see any params? 
   It seems that it get different navigation prop in navigationOptions defined while creating navigator than in the one on component level, but why and does it even operate correctly?